# Android: Problem with onMeasure()

Tags: android, layout

I made a custom view. If I add the view to the layout XML file and I set the height to `fill_parent` "specSize" return 0. Why?

Code:

```
    @Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int measuredHeight = 90;

        int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
        int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec));

        if(specMode != MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED){
         measuredHeight = specSize;
        }
        setMeasuredDimension(60, measuredHeight);
}
```

Does anyone know how I can get the height of `fill_parent`?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to call `MeasureSpec.getMode` inside of call to 'getSize' whole idea of measure spec is to combine way of measuring ( knowing as Spec) and associated Size. See documentation for `MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec` method.So correct code will look something like:

```
int widthSpec = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct code will be:

```
int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);     ----This was already correct
int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);     ----This is corrected.
```